# How do i successfully push my app to heroku using git without getting the 'src refspec does not exist' error?

Tags: django

Wanted to deploy my app on heroku using Git but whenever I try running the command `git push heroku main`, I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/edgarcollections.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may cause due to incorrect branch name.

Try this:

```
git push heroku master
```

or double check your branches.